# PHP, вывод результата команды exec

Tags: php

Доброй ночи!
Не могу вывести результат выполнения exec.
Например:

```
$output = array();
exec("crontab -l", $output);
print_r($output, true);
```

или

```
echo exec("crontab -l");
```

и прочие вариации.

Всегда выводит пустоту.
Каким образом можно вывести результат выполнения команды?

Нужна не именно crontab -l. Это только для примера.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у вас не настроен вывод ошибок, поэтому нет сообщений о том, что данная функция отключена в связи с соображениями безопасности. Вызов отключенных функций вызывает ошибку **E_WARNING,** которая не приводит к завершению работы скрипта.

**Функции:** exec, system, passthru, readfile, shell_exec, escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, proc_close, proc_open, ini_alter, dl, popen, parse_ini_file, show_source.

**По умолчанию, отключены в конфигурации PHP.** Так как именно они чаще всего применяются во вредоносных скриптах и создают угрозу безопасности системы при неправильном использовании или нарушении общих принципов безопасности.

Для того чтобы разрешить выполнение определенных функций или всех, нужно удалить из файла настроек в **disable_functions** файла **php.ini** или закоментировать эту строку. Выглядит данная строка следующим образом:

```
disable_functions = "exec,system,passthru,readfile,shell_exec,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,proc_close,proc_open,ini_alter,dl,popen,parse_ini_file,show_source,curl_exec,pcntl_exec,expect_popen"
```

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, но таки нет. В disable_functions ничего нет. При включении отображения ошибок выводится так же пустота.

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev Попробуйте ``echo exec("whoami");``, если ничего не выведет, то тогда попробовать вот так: ``echo exec("whoami 2>&1");``

Comment: Исправно вывело "apache". Может быть, тут имеют место права доступа? (Предположение с моей недалёкой позиции))

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev По сути, должно выдавать ошибку, если доступа нет. Если бы не выполнялось совсем, тогда бы в /etc/passwd у пользователя apache стоял бы /bash/false. Попробуйте выполнить crontab -l 2>&1, это позволяет переправить поток ошибок в stdout

Comment: Возвращает "no crontab for apache"